# Changing DIV placement in a responsive design from WEB to Mobile version only with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

wondering if there is a way to solve this only with CSS and HTML. Most probably its easy with JS but I want to try without first.

I have on the web version 2 width equals DIV's 50% width each.
Inside of div 1 I have a row and another div 3.
In the mobile version I change the order of the div's at one bracking point so 2 is on the top of 1.
Can I place the DIV 3 that's inside of 1 right at the top, where now DIV  1 starts? only with CSS and without using position absolute? because absolute position will make the div 3 shifting at scroll depending on the width..I have tried to sketch something in photo's attached.
one is for desktop other for mobile

Thank you all in advance for support!

```css
.row1{

background-color: yellow;
width:100%;
display:flex;
}

.div_left {
background-color: blue;
display:relative;
width:25%;
height:200px;
margin-left:25%;
}

.img_mob{
background-color: red;
height:50px;
width:50px;
margin-top:30%;
margin-right:5%;
float:right;
}

.div_right{
background-color: green;
display:relative;
width:25%;
height:200px;
float:right;
}
.main_name {
float:left;
font-size:40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid">

    <!------------ DIV LEFT -->
    <div class="row1">
    
      <div class="div_left">
      <div class="row no-gutters img_mobile ">
          <div class="col">
            <img class="img_mob" src="./media/index.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
          <!------------ DIV RIGHT -->
        <div class="div_right">
        <!-- MAIN NAME -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="main_name">
            <h2>BLALALLA <br>BLALALLA  </h2>
            <h5>
              .......
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>    
</section>
```

Web:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative CSS units like ems, rems, vw, wh, etc. instead of pixels for a responsive website. That would definitely work; you don't need to use JavaScript mandatorily for a responsive design.

Comment: Thx but I think you you don't get my point here. I'm talking about an  abnormal flow of the components  shifting @mediaquery. Normally I use % in all the positioning..

Answer (score 0):

This thing can only be done by JavaScript, not by CSS. Try JS